# set select element and a div to the same height

Tags: html, css

How to set `btn` height to be the same as `sela` height while:

- keeping both `font-size:1.1rem`
- keeping text `PLUS` inside `btn` vertically centered

```css
.wrap{background:green; text-align:center;}
.sela{display:inline-block; margin:0 9px; font-size:1.1rem; outline:none; border:none;}
.btn{display:inline-block; margin:0 9px; background:white; color:black; font-size:1.1rem;}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
<select class='sela'>
<option>lorem ipsum</option>
</select>
<div class='btn'>PLUS</div>
</div>
```

Comment: make `wrap` a flex container? you will have the stretch behavior

Comment: @TemaniAfif, example, pls

Comment: simply add `display: flex;` to wrap

Comment: @TemaniAfif, added, and `wrap` is not now `text-align:center`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check please [code example with fixes on Codepen](https://codepen.io/nat-davydova/pen/gVLRdV).

You need to use flex here:

```
.wrap{background:green; text-align:center; display: flex; justify-content: center;}
.btn{display:flex; margin:0 9px; background:white; color:black; font-size:1.1rem; align-items: center;}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will help -:

```
.wrap{background:green;display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center}
.sela{height: 30px; border: none; font-size:1.1rem;margin-right: 10px;}
.btn{display: flex;align-items: center;background:white; color:black; font-size:1.1rem;height: 30px; border-radius: 5px;border: 1px solid #ccc}
```